# ActiveSheet.Paste problem with updating for second Paste?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

i have some VBA code that seems to work - kinda

it takes some HTML code and uses cut and paste to display the actual HTML rather than just text - this comes from Macro record which I did once and now want to expand to more HTML links

the code actually works - except for one small problem

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Range("A1").Select 'Start in the first cell
    
    ActiveCell.Formula = "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td><br><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><a href='/cmn/chrt/chrt_wrap.php?period=4&epic=ARS' target='window'><img border='0' src='http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=ARS&p=4&t=46' width='335' height='232' alt='6 Month chart.'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>"
    
    Range("B2").Select 'move to B2 just so the graph is not squashed in the corner of the worksheet 
    
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial 'paste the HTML Code
    
    Range("A1").Select 'select the cell with the code in
    
    ActiveCell.Value = "" 'and remove the code - so it looks better
    
    ActiveCell.Formula = "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td><br><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><a href='/cmn/chrt/chrt_wrap.php?period=4&epic=EML' target='window'><img border='0' src='http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=EML&p=4&t=46' width='335' height='232' alt='6 Month chart.'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>" 'get the HTML Graph 2 lines
     
    Range("H2").Select 'move to Cell H2 - so the spacing on the sheet looks good for the graph size
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' paste HTML2 code
    
    Range("A1").Select ' tidy up
    
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
    
End Sub
```

so what I intended was

1. create the activecell.formula
2. Write/paste it out
3. tidy up the cell by deleting the code
4. create HTML code 2
5. write/paste out code 2
6. tidy up

so I get graphs on a page with no background lines of HTML code visible.

what seems to happen is that the first paste works ok

but even tho I change the activecell.formula correctly - I have seen that if I use a msgbox to show the activecell.formula out to screen.... when the activesheet.paste happens for paste 2 it always still has the code for Paste1 . (HTML CODE 1)

so I get the two HTML links working - but they are both on Paste1 ( so showing the ARS link twice ) not showing the ARS as Paste1 and the EML as paste2 ?

I assume even with setting the activecell.formula to the write HTML code - something within the paste is not being overwritten for the second paste ???

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Excel are you using ?

Comment: hi it is the M365 version Ver 2102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think I found the problem - seems to be a slight difference between the Office ClipBoard and the System Clipboard - so when I CNTL-C and CNTL-V manually I guess it goes into the system clipboard... but within VBA it goes into an office clipboard ???

thats why it seems to work manually , but not in VBA... so I have changed the code slightly to be move specific and this seems to work 100% of the time now...

Sub Macro1()

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Graphs").Delete

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Graphs"

Sheets("Graphs").Activate

Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td><br><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><a href='/cmn/chrt/chrt_wrap.php?period=4&epic=ARS' target='window'><img border='0'src='http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=ARS&p=4&t=46' width='335' height='232' alt='6 Month chart.'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>"

Worksheets("Graphs").Range("A1").Copy

DataObj.SetText ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

DataObj.PutInClipboard

Range("B2").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.Value = ""
       
Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td><br><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><a href='/cmn/chrt/chrt_wrap.php?period=4&epic=EML' target='window'><img border='0'src='http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=EML&p=4&t=46' width='335' height='232' alt='6 Month chart.'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>"

Worksheets("Graphs").Range("A1").Copy

DataObj.SetText ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

DataObj.PutInClipboard

Range("H2").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
                      
Range("A1").Select

ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

End Sub

by keep going back to A1 and create/ copy / delete the HTML code - then at the end the sheet is just full of graphs, no spurious text etc....

Thanks for all the contributions to the original request ....

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code out and interestingly H2 had a hyperlink, but it was completely invisible, and I was unable to make it visible.

But try the following; just change the H2 to the second address you're needing

```
Sub HTML()
With Sheets(1)
.Hyperlinks.Add Range("B2"), Address:="http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=ARS&p=4&t=46"
.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H2"), Address:="http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=ARS&p=4&t=46"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks - in the code I created the anctal HTML code is executed - so I get a the graph from the link actually displayed.... so it pulls the link information into the EXcel sheet... but does the above just put the link into the sheet - so you then have to click on the link to get to the web page ?

Comment: The code you provided above does not generate a graph when I run it in Excel.

Comment: not sure if I can add screen shots to this ? but when I run it I do get the HTML Code executed and then I see not the text - but the actual page which the HTML code points to... so i see the web page as presented - not HTML Text

Comment: I understand the situation, but the code you provided above does not generate a graph. Is there another reason the graph is in your excel file? Have you tried to run the code you provided in a blank workbook and not the one you typically use?

Comment: thanks - thats really interesting - so I copied the code into a new blank excel sheet - and then you are right - it fails - and just shows me the HTML text -  but in the original sheet it does show the actual graph which the HTML links to.... very strange.... let me see if I can get to the bottom of why there is a difference between sheets...

Comment: When you click the chart image does the chart itself work as a hyperlink?

Comment: hi - sorry for the slow reply - if I take the line "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td><br><br><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><a href='/cmn/chrt/chrt_wrap.php?period=4&epic=EML' target='window'><img border='0' src='http://uk.advfn.com/p.php?pid=staticchart&s=EML&p=4&t=46' width='335' height='232' alt='6 Month chart.'></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>" and paste it into a new sheet it shows me the text only

Comment: - however when I take that line and cut and paste from that sheet - and repaste - it then works .... so copy from spreadsheet one - into spreadsheet 2 - then select the cell with all the text in and from the ribbon bar select all the text .... then go to a new cell and CNTL-V and then the graph appears ..... so the link is def working .

Comment: ... then within the link some of the CHAR are linked to specific text - so the ARS part will be changed for link to to EML - hence I was trying to use the ActiveCell.Formula and once working I was going to change that to be ActiveCell.Formula = some string and then just change the string each time....

Comment: Highlight and copy and paste the text above without the quotes and paste it? Does it work? I think you're copying the picture of the chart from the workbook

Comment: hi - thanks for spending some time looking at this .... nope it does not work..... so I kinda get 50/50 type success depending on the various cut and paste approach I take .... don't want to waste your time - so let me do some digging and work out the repeatable approach so it makes more sense. thanks